# How to call a child class with no parameter in contructor in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, constructor, multiple-inheritance

I have a Multiple Parent class and the superparent class is the

```py
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    
    def print_name(self):
        print("The item name is " + self.name)
```

and the base class is:

```py
class Gadget(Item):
    def __init__(self, name,
       version):
        self.name = name
        self.version = version
 
    def print_attribute(self):
       pass
       #do for attribute
```

The child of the base class is:

```py
class Mobile_Phone(Gadget):
    def __init__():
        pass
```

so when i instatiate the child class

```py
item = Mobile_Phone("Iphone", "iOS")
item.print_name()
```

it gives me an error the contuctor has 0 positional argument but 3 were given

Comment: You need to initialize parent class attributes first

Comment: Why does Mobile_Phone have __init__() with zero parameters if you're trying to pass multiple parameters into its constructor?

Comment: this is the instruction that were given:                         # Define each child class with the proper parent.
# The constructor should accepts no parameters, and should call its parent's constructor passing the appropriate parameters based on the actual item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand the concept of OOPs and if you send arguments during object construction then your constructor should have parameters to hold the arguments.

item.py

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    
    def print_name(self):
        print("The item name is " + self.name)
```

Gadget.py

```
from item import Item

class Gadget(Item):
    def __init__(self, name, version):
        Item.__init__(self, name)
        self.version = version
 
    def print_attribute(self):
       print(self.name)
       print(self.version)
```

Mobile_Phone.py

```
from Gadget import Gadget

class Mobile_Phone(Gadget):
    def __init__(self, name, version):
        Gadget.__init__(self, name, version)


item = Mobile_Phone("Iphone", "iOS")
item.print_name()
```

Output:

```
The item name is Iphone
```

Answer (score 1):

If your child class initializer doesn't do anything with the arguments you're passing, then they're lost. In the model you've outlined, you could simply omit the initializer in the child class to get what you want.

```py
class MobilePhone(Gadget):  # PEP8 calls for CamelCase here
    pass
```

In this case, the initializer inherited from `Gadget` is setting `self.name` which the inherited `Item.print_name` references.